# How to get the input value after an other event in jsf?

Tags: ajax, jsf

hava an inputText and a gmap

```
 <h:inputText class="text" value="#{restaurant.address}" />
<p:gmap id="gmap" center="21.027845,105.852268" zoom="12" type="ROADMAP"   
        style="width:360px;height:388px"  
        model="#{restaurant.emptyModel}"   
        onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"   
        widgetVar="map">
```

First, `address=""`, when i click on gmap, `address="xxx"` not null.So how can i show its value in inputText tag after clicking on gmap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an ajax event to the map

```
   <p:gmap id="gmap" center="21.027845,105.852268" zoom="12" 
       type="ROADMAP" style="width:360px;height:388px"  
       model="#{restaurant.emptyModel}"   
       onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);" widgetVar="map">
     <p:ajax event="pointSelect" update="theInputText"/>
   </p:gmap>
```

Where `theInputText` is going to be the id of the `<p:inputText/>` to be updated